# Eclipse over X11 forwarding is not showing all icons/assets

Tags: ssh, eclipse, x11-forwarding

I have a virt running RHEL5 which has Eclipse installed on it. I'm using SSH -Y to start eclipse on my Ubuntu host.

My problem is that not all assets in Eclipse seem to be shown. Some of the menus have icons next to them when running from the Virt, like the Egit TEAM menu for example. These assets don't appear when I'm running Eclipse from Ubuntu through SSH.

If I remote using NoMachine NX instead, I'll see the assets be properly displayed. I would rather use a normal SSH X11 forwarding then NX though, any thoughts?